# Для чего нужен PURL?

Tags: веб-программирование, url

Можете человеческим языком объяснить, что такое PURL, для чего он нужен и как его включить/выключить?
Просто на сайте возникла проблема: путь к стилю прописан правильно, файл стилей тоже правильный, а на страницы стиль подтягивается вообще какой-то левый. `.htaccess` об этом молчит, при переименовании файла стилей все начинает работать.

Собственно, [страница](http://pastebin.com/k22tFMb4).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru">
<head profile="http://purl.org/uF/2008/03/">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Кайзен Консалтинг</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="юристы, адвокаты, юридическая помощь, арбитражные споры, налоговые споры, корпоративные споры, административные правонарушения, подготовка правовых заключений, взыскание долга, составление брачного договора, раздел имущества, жилищные споры" />
    <meta name="description" content="Юристы и адвокаты компании Кайзен Консалтинг имеют богатый опыт успешной защиты интересов клиентов в судах общей юрисдикции и арбитражных судах  по гражданским, налоговым, корпоративным, семейным, административным и иным делам" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="logo">
            <a rel="home" href="index.html"><i></i><img src="img/logo.gif" alt="Кайзен Консалтинг" /></a>
            <p>Решение рядом</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="b-icons">
                <div class="icons"><a href="sitemap.html"><i></i></a> <a href="search.html"><b></b></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="phone">
                +7&nbsp;(495) 589-05-06
                <p>информационный центр</p>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Юридическая консалтинговая компания</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="left">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">О&nbsp;компании</a></li>
                <li><a href="mission.html">Миссия</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">Новости</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Услуги</a>
                    <ul class="services">
                        <li><a href="physical.html">Физическим лицам</a></li>
                        <li><a href="legal.html">Юридическим лицам</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="information.html">Полезная информация</a></li>
                <li><a href="publications.html">Наши публикации</a></li>
                <li><a href="consultations.html">Консультации</a></li>
                <li class="contacts"><a href="contacts.html"><i></i>Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Проблемы с&nbsp;налогами?</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a title="Налоговое консультирование" href="tax-consulting.html">Налоговое консультирование</a></li>
                <li><a title="Налоговые споры" href="tax-spores.html">Налоговые споры</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <h1>Юридическая компания &laquo;Кайзен Консалтинг&raquo;</h1>
            <p>Компания &laquo;Кайзен Консалтинг&raquo; специализируется на&nbsp;оказании квалифицированной юридической помощи физическим и&nbsp;юридическим лицам в&nbsp;различных отраслях права, защищает интересы клиентов в&nbsp;арбитражных судах и&nbsp;судах общей юрисдикции по&nbsp;гражданским, налоговым, корпоративным, семейным, административным и&nbsp;иным делам.</p>
            <p>Юристы и&nbsp;адвокаты нашей компании не&nbsp;разрешают дела своих клиентов &laquo;по&nbsp;шаблону&raquo;, а&nbsp;разрабатывают индивидуальное решение поставленной задачи, с&nbsp;учётом всех нюансов конкретного дела, совершая при этом все действия, необходимые и&nbsp;достаточные для получения желаемого результата.</p>
            <p>Обратившись в&nbsp;компанию &laquo;Кайзен Консалтинг&raquo;, вы&nbsp;сможете быть уверенными в&nbsp;том, что получите действительно квалифицированную юридическую помощь с&nbsp;индивидуальным подходом.</p><br />
            <div class="teasers">
                <div class="bottle">
                    <a href="driving-certificate.html">Возврат водительских прав</a>
                    <img src="img/bottle.jpg" alt="Лишили прав?" />
                </div>
                <div class="house">
                    <a href="http://www.kaizen-c.ru/division-of-property.html">Раздел имущества</a>
                    <img src="img/house.jpg" alt="Раздел имущества" />
                </div>
                <div class="baby">
                    <a href="paternity.html">Установление отцовства</a>
                    <img src="img/baby.jpg" alt="Установление отцовства" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer vcard">
        <div class="left">
            <span class="copy">&copy; 2009-2010&nbsp;<a class="fn org url work" href="http://www.kaizen-c.ru">ЗАО &laquo;Кайзен Консалтинг&raquo;</a></span>
            <script id="top100Counter" type="text/javascript" src="http://counter.rambler.ru/top100.jcn?1786696"></script>
            <noscript><div><img src="http://counter.rambler.ru/top100.cnt?1786696" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></div></noscript>
            <p><a rel="nofollow" href="http://top100.rambler.ru/home?id=1786696"><img class="banner" src="http://top100-images.rambler.ru/top100/w0.gif" alt="Rambler's Top100" /></a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="adr">
                <span class="postal-code">119019</span>, <span class="country-name">Россия</span>, <span class="locality">г.&nbsp;Москва</span>, <span class="street-address">Гоголевский бульвар, 17</span>, <span>строение 1</span>, <span>офис 306</span>.<br />
                Телефон: <span class="tel">(495) 589-05-06</span>.<br />
                E-mail: <a class="email" href="mailto:info&#64;kaizen-c.ru">info&#64;kaizen-c&#46;ru</a>
            </div>
            <div class="author">
                <div>Сделано в&nbsp;<a rel="copyright" href="http://www.simweb.su/">Simweb</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-11713080-1");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Раскройте вот это - "какой-то левый". Что именно это значит

Comment: То и значит, что какой-то левый. На сервере файл отсутствует, стили в нем не те и откуда он тянется, понять решительно невозможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, ваша проблема с "левым стилем" не имеет никакого отношения к PURL, т.к. PURL в данном случае используется только в качестве перманентной ссылке на метаданные, которые никак не влияют на работу браузеров.

Скорее всего проблема кроется в вашем сервере. По этому, я бы предложил сделать следующее:

1. Открыть в браузере консоль разработчика(FireBug, Dragonfly), включите логирование всех запросов и убедится, что по соответствующему URL приходит не то, что ожидается.
2. Включить детальный вывод логов и проследить что именно отдается по соответствующему URL
3. Проверить сервер на наличие rootkit'ов и прочих посторонних скриптов.

Comment: Спасибо). Посмотрел, действительно проблема на сервере - IP сайта каким-то странным образом пересекся с IP другого сайта, поэтому стиль тянулся оттуда.

Answer (score 2):

PURL (англ. Persistent Uniform Resource Locator) — постоянный единообразный локатор (определитель местонахождения) ресурса. На английский манер произносится как [пурл], русское произношение ещё не устоялось, вероятно это будет [пу-эр-э́л] или [пурла́]. Формат PURL основан на URL — стандартизированном способе записи адреса ресурса в сети Интернет. PURL — это постоянный локатор ресурса, который (в отличие от обычного URL) не может измениться.

Больше [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PURL).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на Википедию, но я это уже читал. Меня больше интересует, как это работает и как это включить/выключить. Пока все, что я понял, это PURL - нестандартная замена htaccess'у. Но почему эта технология по умолчанию поддерживается браузерами?

Comment: А при чем тут вообще браузеры и .htaccess? Насколько я понял, это всего-лишь сервис (концепция сервиса) по хранению и управлению "умными" редиректами. Т.е. что-то вроде сервиса по сокращению ссылок вроде [goo.gl](http://goo.gl/), только более продвинутый.

Comment: Вот этого-то я и не понял. У меня есть примерный кусок кода: `<head profile="http://purl.org/xX/0000/00/">` и данные тянутся фиг знает откуда. При удалении `profile="..."` изменений не происходит - стало быть, браузер запоминает, откуда тянуть данные. То есть, это уже веб-стандарт?  
Кеш я постоянно сбрасываю.

Comment: > <head profile="http://purl.org/xX/0000/00/">

У `<head>` нет никаких атрибутов, т.ч. этот кусок едва-ли способен повлиять на что-либо кроме валидатора.

Мой совет: откройте в браузере консоль разработчика(FireBug, Dragonfly), включите логирование всех запросов, нажмите ctrl+f5 и посмотрите в заголовках ответа кто куда редиректит и кто что отдает.

Comment: Нет, это не стандарт. у body нету атрибута profile, видимо за это отвечает какая то js библиотека

Comment: Наврал, [атрибут profile](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.3) у `<head>` оказывается действительно есть, однако на браузер он не должен никак влиять. Разве что-либо расширения браузера могут его использовать.

Comment: Добавил ссылку в вопрос.

Comment: Кажется теперь я понял. Вас смутил именно этот `profile="http://purl.org/xX/0000/00/"`?

Думаю, что никакого отношения к вашей проблеме это не имеет, т.к. это всего-лишь ссылка на http://buzzword.org.uk/profiles/2008/03/

Comment: ой, чето я еще не проснулся. Я с body перепутал :) Сорь. Что собственно в сообщении и написал :) Про body :)